# How can separate the touchscreen to left and right side in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new in android and this is my first android project. I want to separate the screen to left and right side and when you press left side I want to do some action and on right side other action. Here is my input class:

```
package com.vratsasoftware.zbhelpers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.BonusLogo;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameobjects.Logo;
import com.vratsasoftware.gameworld.GameWorld;
import com.vratsasoftware.ui.SimpleButton;

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {
    private Logo myLogo;
    BonusLogo bullet;
    private GameWorld myWorld;
    private List<SimpleButton> menuButtons;
    private SimpleButton playButton;
    private float scaleFactorX;
    private float scaleFactorY;

    public InputHandler(GameWorld myWorld, float scaleFactorX, float scaleFactorY) {
        this.myWorld = myWorld;
        myLogo = myWorld.getLogo();
        int midPointY = myWorld.getMidPointY();
        this.scaleFactorX = scaleFactorX;
        this.scaleFactorY = scaleFactorY;
        menuButtons = new ArrayList<SimpleButton>();
        playButton = new SimpleButton(136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.playButtonUp.getRegionWidth() / 2), midPointY + 50, 29, 16,
                AssetLoader.playButtonUp, AssetLoader.playButtonDown);
        menuButtons.add(playButton);
        bullet = myWorld.getScroller().getBullet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        screenX = scaleX(screenX);
        screenY = scaleY(screenY);
        System.out.println(screenX + " " + screenY);
        if (myWorld.isMenu()) {
            playButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
        } else if (myWorld.isReady()) {
            myWorld.start();
        }

        myLogo.onClick();

        if (myWorld.isGameOver() || myWorld.isHighScore()) {
            myWorld.restart();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        screenX = scaleX(screenX);
        screenY = scaleY(screenY);

        if (myWorld.isMenu()) {
            if (playButton.isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
                myWorld.ready();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // Can now use Space Bar to play the game
        if (keycode == Keys.SPACE) {
            if (myWorld.isMenu()) {
                myWorld.ready();
            } else if (myWorld.isReady()) {
                myWorld.start();
            }
            myLogo.onClick();
            if (myWorld.isGameOver() || myWorld.isHighScore()) {
                myWorld.restart();
            }
        } else if (keycode == Keys.CONTROL_RIGHT && bullet.isScrolledRight()) {
            Sound.playKick();
            bullet.resetBullet(myWorld.getLogo().getX(), (int) myWorld.getLogo().getY());
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

    private int scaleX(int screenX) {
        return (int) (screenX / scaleFactorX);
    }

    private int scaleY(int screenY) {
        return (int) (screenY / scaleFactorY);
    }

    public List<SimpleButton> getMenuButtons() {
        return menuButtons;
    }
}
```

I want when I press left side to do this

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    screenX = scaleX(screenX);
    screenY = scaleY(screenY);
    System.out.println(screenX + " " + screenY);
    if (myWorld.isMenu()) {
        playButton.isTouchDown(screenX, screenY);
    } else if (myWorld.isReady()) {
        myWorld.start();
    }

    myLogo.onClick();

    if (myWorld.isGameOver() || myWorld.isHighScore()) {
        myWorld.restart();
    }
    return true;
}
```

and when I press the right side to do other action. Can someone help me about this ?

Comment: In what `Activity` you are using this class? And how they cooperates?

Comment: I made game like flappy bird and when I press the screen it jump this is the activity at the moment but I want to make it jump only when I press the left side and when I press the right side I want it to shoot with bullet like here `if (keycode == Keys.CONTROL_RIGHT && bullet.isScrolledRight()) {
            Sound.playKick();
            bullet.resetBullet(myWorld.getLogo().getX(), (int) myWorld.getLogo().getY());
        }`
And this class cooperate with GameScreen class where start the game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you have `X` coordinate of click event. I know 2 ways to detect in what side it was.

1) Use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()` to detect display width. It will work only if your work space expanded for full screen.

2) Get reference for main activity layout and call `getWidth()`. This solution is better if you have reference to layout inside your `InputHandler` class.

I guess, you know what to do with display width.